# Display HTML from access DB while showing the background of the form?

Tags: c#, ms-access

So I am trying to display HTML from a column in an access DB. I am able to do this using this below.

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

The problem is I want the control to be "transparent" basically show the text with html formatting but show the form background behind it... and I have not found a way to do that.

Is there another way to display this HTML while showing the form background and keep the format of the contents? The HTML is just text with li tags etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying a style to the stored HTML? You can make things transparent, or coloured using a CSS style.

Comment: I am talking about the whole webBrowser control... The html in the DB has styles and this can change, I did not create the DB and it will sometimes be a different version etc. I only want to use the webBrowser control as a placeholder for the HTML in the DB. But I want the background of the text area to be transparent so the form background image will be displayed etc. Hopefully that makes sense.